# Ubuntu 14.01 LTS can't access some websites

Tags: networking, dns

Something is wrong with Ubuntu Kernel and Windows DHCP,DNS Server.

First i will explain my problem in few words and then ill post all my configurations.

My ubuntu computer is behind a all-in-one Windows Server DHCP,DNS , Firewall.

My ubunut installation is not able to ping , traceroute , telnet some websites. Ive walk trough all the TCP/IP stack troubleshooting and im still not able to see what is wrong.

80-90 percent of other websites work good . Everything seems to get solved if i connect my computer directly to the router( a DSL connection)

I have other Linux and windows machines ( Centos and Windows 7) and they all work without any problem, is just with Ubuntu. Ive updated and reinstalled many times and still not getting the issue.

I even have tcpdump on the ubuntu machine and wireshark on the windows server and i see traffic coming in  for all the working sites and failed requests for those who not.

Here is my ifconfig:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan1
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:4b:a2:4d:89  
      inet addr:192.168.0.69  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::290:4bff:fea2:4d89/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3284931 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:536403 (536.4 KB)
```

Here is my route:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
```

Here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubica-HP-Pavilion

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And the /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search GPS.LOCAL
```

Ive changed DNS to Google's and OPENDNS's address and rebooted and nothing happens. Actually the non accesible site are resolved well, here is an example:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ dig www.ubica.com.sv

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> www.ubica.com.sv
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35868
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ubica.com.sv.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ubica.com.sv.   86400   IN  A   209.239.120.202

;; Query time: 185 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 01 19:10:48 CST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

And Pinging www.ubica.com.sv , gets resolved but it never answers ICMP requests:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ ping www.ubica.com.sv
PING www.ubica.com.sv (209.239.120.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.69 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- www.ubica.com.sv ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 14148ms
```

and a traceroute to the same address pings back to itself:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ traceroute www.ubica.com.sv
traceroute to www.ubica.com.sv (209.239.120.202), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.69 (192.168.0.69)  2997.073 ms !H  2997.006 ms !H  2996.993 ms !H
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$
```

If i ping or traceroute any other site it works fine:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ ping www.godaddy.com
PING e8804.a.akamaiedge.net (96.17.125.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a96-17-125-116.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (96.17.125.116): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=98.2 ms
64 bytes from a96-17-125-116.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (96.17.125.116): icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=101 ms
```

There are not IPtables entrys and the firewall is off:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 

administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

As i said before , Centos and Windows machines are able to access the same site without any trouble so i can probably discard the windows server. And as soon as i connect my ubuntu machine directly to the DSL it starts working without trouble.

Ive also checked using one of the IPs of the CentOS machines just to be sure that there is nothing blocking at IP level.

Here is the tcpdump of the ubuntu machine for interface when i try to ping a not workking host:

```
administrator@ubica-HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo tcpdump -c 10 -i wlan1 host 192.168.0.69tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:27:39.586609 IP 192.168.0.69.2663 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 7253+ A? www.ubica.com.sv. (34)
19:27:40.200841 IP 192.168.0.69.37076 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 43428+ PTR? 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (42)
19:27:44.591912 IP 192.168.0.69.2663 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 7253+ A? www.ubica.com.sv. (34)
19:27:45.203612 IP 192.168.0.69.37076 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 43428+ PTR? 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (42)
19:27:45.391250 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.69 tell 192.168.0.1, length 46
19:27:45.391327 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.69 is-at 00:90:4b:a2:4d:89 (oui Unknown), length 28
19:27:45.405816 IP 192.168.0.1.domain > 192.168.0.69.2663: 7253 1/0/0 A 209.239.120.202 (50)
19:27:45.406365 ARP, Request who-has static-ip-209-239-120-202.inaddr.ip-pool.com tell 192.168.0.69, length 28
19:27:45.560263 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.60 is-at 00:f4:28:00:29:a7 (oui Unknown), length 46
19:27:46.403509 ARP, Request who-has static-ip-209-239-120-202.inaddr.ip-pool.com tell 192.168.0.69, length 28
19:27:46.563522 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.60 is-at 00:f4:28:00:29:a7 (oui Unknown), length 46
11 packets captured
24 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Please i need some more ideas in order to troubleshoot what is going on. Its not a single host trouble , it happens with many others i just used ubica.com.sv as an example.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more about your DNS client config details? And can you check [this que page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2152047) on domain/DNS?

Comment: Could you post /etc/network/interfaces? [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution) is a useful link.

Comment: IMO, it's not a DNS problem. What looks strange to me here are those ARP requests: they ask for the MAC address of an host which can't be on the local network. Of course, there's no reply, and probably this is why the ping request fails. Now, how could happen ARP is told to ask for an host name ?

Comment: Actually there is nothing wrong with DNS , i can resolve any address by any method , ping , traceroute , dns , but after the ip has been resolved i can not achieve connectivity ( ping the IP ). As Pyrophorus said , im also suspicious about the ARP requests of a host that it is not in the local network , it should be redirected to the gateway.

Comment: Ive also tried adding a static ARP , and a static route for a specific host but it also fails.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?  14.01 is not a valid version  of Ubuntu.

Comment: Try `ip route show table all`. Your system doesn't appear to be using the default gateway for traffic to `209.239.120.202`. `ip route show table all` will show you interface routes, directly-connected routes, policy-based routes, and other such routing entries that can supersede the main routing table.

Answer (score 0):

From your ifconfig, I see that your MTU value is 1500. Try lowering it, first to 1492, then 1480 and so on and see if you can access the sites. Use

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 mtu <new value> up
```

I had a similar problem and lowering my MTU value from 1500 to 1492 solved it.